# 400 Error while uploading blob on Cloud Storage

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have created a csv file in Cloud Function. Now, I need to upload it on Cloud Storage. I stored it in /tmp file. From there, I have to upload it on Cloud Storage.

Code used -

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_file(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(source_file_name,destination_blob_name))

final_df.to_csv('/tmp/'+file_name)
with open('/tmp/'+file_name, 'r') as file_obj:
    upload_blob('test-bucket',file_obj,file_name)
```

But, I am facing the following error -

```
BadRequest: 400 PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/test-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ABC: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, 308)
```

File is getting stored in the /tmp folder. From there, it is not getting uploaded. What exactly can be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of possible reasons for the [400 error Bad request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#400_Bad_Request) (not 404). Maybe you should specify the full path and you don't have open the file and pass it in the source_file_name. Here's what I've tried to successfully upload an object (tried it with an mp3 file) to GCS

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload_blob ("[bucketname]", "/home/[username]/[filename]", "[filename]")
```

Comment: This helped. Instead of opening the file and uploading, I uploaded directly. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries.. :)